# Command Line in Batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I am making a batch file to automate mysql installation silently.  When I type the following line in the command prompt everything works fine.

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName="mydb" RootPassword="pos" ServerType=DEVELOPMENT DatabaseType=INNODB Port=3306

My question is: can I somehow add this to a batch file so it will run it as if I entered it in the command line?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Of course. If you copy-and-paste that into a `script.bat` file and run that file it'll do it as is. But I feel there is something more that you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, its easy. As Santa commented, just put your command inside some text file, change the extension of that file to .bat. Thats all !!

Comment: I didn't realize the command takes like 2 minutes to complete so I thought it froze. thanks :)